# Does using different Boost versions affect serialization and deserialization?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working on some project in C++ where I'm using Boost for binary serialization and deserialization. Serialization feature is already present with Boost version 1.61 I made my whole deserialization add on feature using Boost version 1.77 and now I'm facing problem while reading binary files. So, my question is how does this difference in version for deserialization affects the process? Because I'm unable to properly read the binary file.

Code using Boost version 1.61 for serialization

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Frame{
public:
    std::string str;
};
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Frame& f, const unsigned int version) {
    ar& f.str;
}

uint32_t main () {
    Frame f={"Frame example"};
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("BinaryFile.bin",std::ios::out, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive write(ofs,boost::archive::no_header);
    write << f;
    ofs.close();
}
```

Code using boost version 1.77 for deserialization

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Frame{
public:
    std::string str;
};
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Frame& f, const unsigned int version) {
    ar& f.str;
}

uint32_t main () {
    Frame f;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("BinaryFile.bin",std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive read(ofs,boost::archive::no_header);
    read >> f;
    ofs.close();
}
```

This is just an example code the frame I am using is different but approach is same.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of code that does serialization & deserialization, such that using Boost 1.61 to serialize, and the same code using Boost 1.77 cannot deserialize?

Comment: TL;DR : you need to have the same boost versions on both sides, otherwise it is not guaranteed to work; I had the same problem in the past and in the end resigned from using boost. Protobuf on the other hand should have some compatibility guaranteed.

Comment: @Eljay I have added the example code you can check it out.

Comment: Thank you for providing the code.  Did it compile and run for you?  It did not compile for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is backwards compatibility. But it requires the archive headers to be present so the library can detect the version support required for de-serialization.

Without the header, there's no way to tell, so the library must assume it's the most current version.

Removing that should work, see it live:

- save in 1.61.0: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PkqDp4fWrno9GLql
- read in 1.76.0: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PAwLOhVg0STNGN59

On my machine the read side worked with the same file in Boost 1.77.0 (not available on wandbox):

```
Success: Frame example
```

### Summarizing

You should probably switch the file format to use the headers. This will probably require some kind of conversion tool. If all else fails you might opt to distinguish the versions by their filename/extension. That's brittle, but if it's the only thing you can control it might save you.

Comment: Added the live demonstration

Comment: This is still not working. Archive version for boost 1.61.0 is 14 while archive version for boost 1.77.0 is 19, Text files are working but binary files are not working.

Comment: I also tried using boost 1.61 for both serialization and deserialization and even that didn't worked for me.

Comment: @Rav please share minimal code so that we can see what the problem is

Comment: @Rav as a blind guess, you had "std::ios::out, std::ios::binary" which is clearly in error. Note how I wrote it in my live demos

Comment: this was only the error and now it is working fine. I want to know why was I getting error because of using `std::ios::out, std::ios::binary`. I'm new to this so it would be a great help. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Encoding stability is not a property of boost serialization itself, but is instead handled on a per-archive basis.

You can use `get_library_version()` on the archive to check for compatibility across boost versions.

> Returns an unsigned integer containing the current version number of the serialization library. This number will be incremented each time the library is altered in such a way that serialization could be altered for some type. [...]

Comment: so using the same version is an easy option?

Comment: In my opinion, you should be checking `get_library_version()` regardless. Even simply checking it against a hard-coded constant is enough to intercept nasty surprises. It's not a matter of **if** a version desync between serialization and deserialization will happen, it's a matter of **when**. It might be years down the line, but I can guarantee you will run into it sooner or later.

Comment: @Rav *"so using the same version is an easy option?"* -- Easy? For a one-developer project, yes. Sustainable in the long term? No.